# Extracting and Adding Numbers From Array(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, numbers

I'm trying to write a function that will extract and summarize all integers, no matter how many levels deep (I'm talking multidimensional arrays here) from a given array. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function addTheNumbers (someArray) {
    var onlyNumbers = someArray.filter(function(a){ return typeof(a)=='number'; });
    for (i = 0; i &lt; onlyNumbers.length; i++) {
        // idk
    }
}
var sampleArray = ['word',['a','b','c'],12314,'longer phrase',5,[123,123,2],10,3874,32];
addTheNumbers(sampleArray);
```

I have two concerns:

**1)** I feel like the filter I have in place will only extract the numbers that are standing alone within the given array and not ALL numbers in ALL arrays… not sure how to fix it.

**2)** I know that once I've got all the numbers extracted, they'll be stored in an object/array, and I'll have to iterate through it somehow to add them all together, but… once again I have no idea how to proceed.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7equtrL/) to make things easier.

Comment: If element is array, apply the addTheNumbers recursively on it.

Comment: Your problem can be described as two smaller problems: 1) flatten the array, 2) sum the elements (if they're numbers).

Comment: `typeof` works without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var temp = [];
function addTheNumbers(someArray) {

 for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
   if(typeof someArray[i] == "number")
   temp.push(someArray[i]);
  else if(typeof someArray[i] == "object"){
   addTheNumbers(someArray[i]);
  }
 };
}


var sampleArray = ['word', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 12314, 'longer phrase', 5, [123, 123, 2], 10, 3874, 32];
addTheNumbers(sampleArray);
```

Comment: This returns "undefined" for me. :/

Comment: You will get the values in "temp" variable

Comment: Okay, so I understand that `someArray` is getting "scanned" for the number type and the values are getting pushed to the `temp` variable, but where are we adding those values together in this?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said, the easier way is a recursive structure.

```js
function addTheNumbers(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (sum, currentValue) {
        if (currentValue instanceof Array) {
            return sum + addTheNumbers(currentValue);
        }
        return sum + (typeof currentValue == "number" ? currentValue : 0);
    }, 0);
}
var sampleArray = ['word',['a','b','c'],12314,'longer phrase',5,[123,123,2],10,3874,32];
alert(addTheNumbers(sampleArray)); // returns 16483
```

Comment: I get everything but line 6—particulary the `?b:0` part. Could you walk me through it?

Comment: It is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)... ( condition ? TRUE : FALSE )

Answer (score 0):

```
    var number = [];
    function addTheNumbers(someArray) {

        for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        if(/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/.test(someArray[i])) {
        number.push(someArray[i]);
    }       
    else if(someArray[i] !== null && typeof someArray[i] === 'object'){
                addTheNumbers(someArray[i]);
            }
        };
    }


    var sampleArray = ['word', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 12314, 'longer phrase', 5, [123, 123, 2], 10, 3874, 32];
addTheNumbers(sampleArray);
```

hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

`r()` is the callback for reducing the array.

```js
var sampleArray = ['word', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 12314, 'longer phrase', 5, [123, [123, 0], 2], 10, 3874, 32];
function r(res, el) {
    if (typeof el === 'number') {
        res.push(el);
    } else if (Array.isArray(el)) {
        res = res.concat(el.reduce(r, []));
    }
    return res;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sampleArray.reduce(r, []), null, 4) + '</pre>');
```